# Pandas Merge Vlookup, KeyError: "['Value'] not in index"

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to perform a vlookup/merge betwen two dataframes. I get the error 
`KeyError: "['Player'] not in index"`

i've tried to reindex the columns but doesnt seem to work.
`df1= df1.reindex(columns = ['Player','Category'])`

My current code is like so `missingnames = pd.merge(df1,df2[['Player','Player Name']],on='Player',how = 'left')`

My dataframes are like below:

df1:

[image]

df2:

[image]

expected output

[image]

can anyone help with this?
Thanks.

Comment: df2 does not have a column `Player`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
df1['Exists'] = df1['Player'].str.lower().isin(df2['Player Name'].str.lower())
```

Comment: does this take into account case sensitivity? ie is one is Lebron James is the other is LEBRON JAMES, will it show false?

Comment: thank you. Does this just convert both columns to lowercase?

Comment: @excelguy It doesn't just uses the lowercase version to do the check.

Comment: but will it show true regardless of case sensitivity?

Comment: @excelguy it will

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df1['Exists']=np.where(df1['Player'].str.upper().isin(df2['Player Name'].str.upper()),'Exists','')
```

Answer (score 1):

Look closer at your merge argument and the columns you have in each dataframe

df1 includes "Player" and "Category"
df2 includes "Player Name", "Height" and "Weight"

Your merge argument says that the column "Player" is in df2 however it is not

`missingnames = pd.merge(df1,df2[['Player','Player Name']],on='Player',how = 'left')`
===============================^

missingnames needs to be changed to:
`missingnames = df1.merge(df2,left_on='Player',right_on='Player Name',how = 'left')`

And then from there ascertain if there are any missing values